# Load the cms content based on theme in cms editor

Tags: magento-1.8, cms, mobile, conditional-loading

I have two different themes one for desktop and one for mobile. I added about-us page content in cms pages. Its working fine in desktop.

Now, the html is different for mobile theme. So, how can I place mobile theme code in the same editor? The content should load based on theme. How can I get frontend theme and write conditions in cms editor.

ex: if(theme = "desktop") {
    desktop about us page should render
} else {
    mobile about us page should render
}

Comment: have you use   multiple store ?

Comment: no, same store but different themes.

Comment: can you please show code of editor thus i can understrand

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using  [`Event observer`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

On **controller_action_predispatch_cms_page_view**

On this event check  current theme by `$Currenttheme=Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme('layout');` on observer and then redirect `from here according to your logic`.

**config.xml**

```
<global> 
    .....
     <events>
    <controller_action_predispatch_cms_page_view> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <controller_action_predispatch_cms_page_view_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento65420/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>addRedirection</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </controller_action_predispatch_cms_page_view_handler>
        </observers>
      </controller_action_predispatch_cms_page_view>
    </events>
    ...
</global>
```

### Edited:

### Use: cms_page_render Event

Better way to use `cms_page_render` event and fire an `observer` this.

**config.xml code like:**

```
  <global>
    <models>
      <magento65420>
        <class>Stackexchangetwo_Magento65420_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>magento65420_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </magento65420>
    </models>
    <events>
      <cms_page_render> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <cms_page_render_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento65420/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>addRedirection</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </cms_page_render_handler>
        </observers>
      </cms_page_render>
    </events>
  </global>
```

Then using `observer parameters page object` and  `current controller redirect to home page.`

```
<?php
class Stackexchangetwo_Magento65420_Model_Observer
{

            public function addRedirection(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {
                 // Mage::dispatchEvent('cms_page_render', array('page' => $page, 'controller_action' => $action));
                 $controller=$observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction(); // Current controller
                 $page=$observer->getEvent()->getPage();// page object 
                 echo  $CurrentTheme=Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme('layout');
                    if($CurrentTheme=='default' && $page->getId()==6){          
                     $controller->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
                     $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl());
                    }

            }

}
```